# MacOS Mojave terminal and colour issues

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, colors, xcode

Since I installed Mojave I have 2 issues:

1. My secondary monitor doesn't show colours right, they are somewhat vague from what they used to be. It's like someone washed out the screen.

I tried restarting, plugging in and out, changing gamma correction and colour scheme, playing with brightness and contrast. Nothing helped.

When I plug it out and back in, for a brief moment it shows the right colours, but once I do any kind of action, like type something, they reset to being vague again. Laptop screen is okay though.

2. My terminal is blocking from time to time, especially when I open a new terminal tab after one is already opened. It just freezes and I need to shut it down and reopen for it to work. There was also an issue with `xcrun` error, but I resolved that part by running `xcode-select --install`

Comment: What specific mac and year are you using? Have you upgraded the graphics?

Comment: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015). I don't know how to update graphics other than doing a complete software update. It's not like Windows drivers as far as I can tell?